# Cast signed to narrower signed

Tags: c++, casting

[If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

If I understand well, is it guaranteed that :

```
static_cast<std::int8_t>(static_cast<std::int16_t>(-3)) == -3
```

?

Because -3 can be represented in an std::int8_t.

Thus in the example of a two s complement:

Then in the example of the [two's complement function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754082/how-to-take-twos-complement-of-a-byte-in-c), do I need an intermediaite cast to std::uintmax_t?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T twos_complement(T val)
{
    typedef std::make_unsigned<T>::type U;

    return static_cast<T>(-static_cast<uintmax_t>(static_cast<U>(val)));
}
```

because

```
return static_cast<T>(-static_cast<U>(val));
```

integral promotion applied before unary minus could "ruin the effect of casting to an unsigned type if T is narrower than int"?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Writting a two's complement function by using only necessary casts.

Comment: What's your question exactly? What do you need help with?

Comment: First: is the value -3 preserved after casting to narrower signed? Second is it necessary in the example of the two's complement to protect against a potential integral promotion in case T is narrower than int .

Comment: It is preserved if it fits into smaller type. So -3 is fine. But -1000 is not in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you get the two's complement like this:

```
uint32_t num = 10;
uint32_t cmp = ~num + 1; // this is two's complement of 10.
```

Doesn't this work for you?

EDIT: if you're worried that an overflow may occur (for either signed or unsigned), just do this first:

```
if(~num == std::numeric_limits<MyIntType>::max()) {
    // overflow mitigation
}
```

You can also statically check whether your type is signed or unsigned to mitigate overflow problems in appropriate ways with [`std::is_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) and [`std::is_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned).

Comment: Is it working for any integer types even for signed integer types (on which overflow is not garanteed to return modulo)?

Comment: @FlashMcQueen If you're worried about overflow, why don't you check if `~num` is max int? You can get that from `numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 2):

Signed/Unsigned representations are platform-dependent. Even if most modern platforms use the two's complement to represent signed numbers, you can not make this assumption. Using `static_cast` to perform a two's complement is not the right way to go. If you want to do bit manipulation yourself, use fixed-size unsigned types as in The Quantum Physicist's answer (but note that again, what will happen in case of overflow on the addition is platform dependent).

Comment: actually... you kind of can make this assumption https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types The committee finally accepted that two's complement is the only used representation and the proposal to require two's complement has been accepted into C++20 https://herbsutter.com/2018/11/13/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-san-diego/

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the code that you linked with C++ casts:

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
T twos_complement(T val)
{
    return static_cast<T>(-static_cast<uintmax_t>(val));
}
```